# How to detect when a form changes from one screen to another

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I need an event or notification that signals when a form changes from one screen to another.

I know I can poll for this, but I'm looking for a non-polling solution.

Comment: What do you mean with _screen change occurs_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ResizeEnd event on Control that is fired when the control is resized or moved.
Then you can use Screen.FromControl() to get the actual screen.
Example :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Screen _actualScreen;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _actualScreen = Screen.FromControl(this);
        this.ResizeEnd += Form1_ResizeEnd;
    }

    private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(_actualScreen != Screen.FromControl(this))
        {
            //Your treatment
        }
    }
}
```

I Hope this solution can help you !

Comment: Seems like a perfectly reasonable solution to me. Thanks, @SaelDev!